# Concatenating large number of rows into a single string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table containing a large number of rows.  Each row has 2 columns which I need to use - the first is some HTML formatting and the second is the text.  I need to concatenate all these rows into a single string value so that I can e-mail this massive string.  Due to the large number of rows I can't use a VARCHAR variable - I have to use text.  The current solution is to use a cursor to read all the rows and then insert into a temporary table with a single column of type text and then simply append to the single row in that table.

The problem is that the string seems to get cutoff after about 33000 characters.  I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

EDIT: I have taken some of the advice from the answers given here and changed the solution to use VARCHAR(MAX).  However I'm still getting cutoff, but in a very odd way.  It doesn't seem like the variable is getting an overflow, it's simply not appending all the values.

```
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Result = ''

SELECT @Result = @Result + ltrim(isnull(format,'')) + '&nbsp;' + text + '<BR></TD></TR><TR><TD CLASS="GEN" align="left" BGCOLOR="#E9ECFD">' 
FROM SomeTable
```

The **really** odd bit is that if I take out the bit where I'm appending all that html at the end of the line, it all works fine.  I've even inserted everything into a tmp table first and then did this concatenation select - still no luck.  The tmp table contains the correct values (including the html), but the final variable doesn't.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not in your SQL but in the calling code or in the display logic

Comment: Have you tried the [XML PATH](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/07/06/871.aspx) trick to concatenate strings to see how it compares?

Comment: Codymanix - well to test it I'm simply going 'SELECT txt FROM TempMessage' - how can that not display correctly?  It's also not coming up correctly in the e-mail - getting cutoff at the same spot

Comment: @Martin Smith Thanks, will take a look

Comment: @Jaco - How are you reviewing the result? Are you sure it just isn't getting truncated in SSMS? That can be set to display only up to a maximum of 65,535 characters.

Comment: @Martin Smith How would I check that?

Comment: @Jaco - The maximum number of characters is set in the "Query Options" dialogue. To avoid truncation you can use this trick `SELECT @longVariable AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH('') `

Comment: @Martin Smith I tried that, but my results get truncated after 2034 characters...

Comment: You need to use results to grid.

Comment: I did use results to Grid... If you go to Query Options, Results -> Grid, the maximum characters received is set to 65535 and you can't increase this value.  I managed to get around this by just writing my own little mini-query analyzer and checking the results in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Due to the large number of rows I
>   can't use a VARCHAR variable - I have
>   to use text

From SQL Server 2005, there is support for VARCHAR(MAX) and NVARCHAR(MAX) to handle large strings over 8000 (4000 for NVARCHAR) characters, up to ~2GB. So as of 2005, you should be looking to use those instead of TEXT/NTEXT which will be being deprecated in a future version of SQL Server.

This support for MAX makes things easier than having to deal with TEXT, so give that a whirl.

Comment: Only issue I had was with SSMS 2008 truncating the output.  It was working correctly, but it wasn't displaying the output correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: I think the main problem is that you are using `varbinary(16)` as the pointer to update your `text` value. A signed 16-bit integer will run out at around 32,768 - so thats probably your problem.

Try using a `bigint` pointer instead of `varbinary`

Also note that `UPDATETEXT` has been deprecated and Microsoft recommends you use `UPDATE` with a `WRITE` clause instead - [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189466(v=SQL.100).aspx).

Example from [this msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523(v=SQL.100).aspx) page:

```
UPDATE Production.Document
SET DocumentSummary .WRITE (N'features',28,10)
```

Similarly, `text` is on the way out and you should probably use `varchar(max)` instead.

Comment: Yeah if I use bigint instead of varbinary the UPDATETEXT fails... Will try that with UPDATE and WRITE

Answer (score -1):

You'd better write the concatenated strings into a file.
To write a string to a file, you could use a SP like this: 
http://www.simple-talk.com/code/WorkingWithFiles/spWriteStringTofile.txt

Comment: Yeah I can't use this solution - I have to pass the string somewhere else.  I would like to know why my string is getting cutoff.